# Cypress: How to connect to Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, cypress

Using Cypress, I need to connect to Dynamo DB and fetch a value from a table.
I have the below piece of code in Javascript. Can someone please guide me as to how to establish a connection and fetch a value from Dynamo DB table thru Cypress.

Note: I am using cypress to test API call. So I have to hit an endpoint and confirm I get 200 OK. After that, I need to connect to Dynamo DB and verify the data. I need to achieve this entire test using Cypress

```
    var AWS = require ('aws-sdk') ;
    AWS.config.update({accessKeyId: 'xxxxxx', 
                       secretAccessKey: 'xxxxxx',
                       region: 'us-east-1'
                                });

    //let AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
    exports.handler = async (event) => {
        // TODO implement
        let tableName = "invoice";
        let idvalue = '100458';
        let id = idvalue.toString();
        console.log('id'+id);
        let params = {
                    TableName: tableName,
                    KeyConditionExpression: "#id = :idvalue",
                    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
                        "#id": "id"
                    },
                    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                        ":idvalue": id
                    }
                };

         let queryParams = await docClient.query(params).promise();
         console.log("query params is>"+queryParams.Items);
         queryParams.Items.forEach(function(item) {
                    console.log('items is'+JSON.stringify(item));
                    });
         return;
```

Comment: What do you mean *"using Cypress"*? Cypress is for driving the browser, though you can make generic requests with [`cy.request`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html).

Comment: You can use cypress to test API as well. So I have to hit an endpoint and confirm I get 200 OK. After that, I need to connect to Dynamo DB and verify the data. I need to achieve this entire test using Cypress.

Comment: So did you *try doing that*? What happened?